# How can I center all tables in a document?

Tags: tables, floats, lyx, horizontal-alignment

### Background

Would like to center all tables within floats, without having to add `\centering` to each table.

### Ideas

Tried the following:

```
\let\originaltabular\tabular
\renewcommand\tabular{\centering\originaltabular}
```

It compiles, but the tables remain left-justified.

### Question

How would you edit the Preamble of a LyX document to make all the floating tables be centred?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you would like to center all tabular environments, I would recommend to create your own environment with a different name, which calls tabular. You could use that instead of redefining tabular itself.

But no problem, this can be done. Just use `\renewenvironment`, for example:

```
\let\originaltabular\tabular
\let\endoriginaltabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \centering%
  \originaltabular{#1}}%
  {\endoriginaltabular\endgroup}
```

This as addition to your first try redefining tabular.

You could redefine the floating table environment very similar:

```
\let\originaltable\table
\let\endoriginaltable\endtable
\renewenvironment{table}[1][ht]{%
  \originaltable[#1]
  \centering}%
  {\endoriginaltable}
```

You could also use [etoolbox to patch the table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95992/centering-all-tables-in-a-document-with-etoolbox) or append `\centering` to the definition this way:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\table}{\centering}
\makeatother
```

or

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\table\expandafter{\table\centering}
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't test this with LyX, but `\usepackage{floatrow}` also centers the contents of floats. (The justification is configurable, but `\centering` is floatrow's default behaviour.)

Comment: You have to use `floatbox` code to use `floatrow`. LyX adds floats as `\begin_inset Float table`; were I hand-coding this in LaTeX, I could try it.

Answer (score 3):

In the Lyx list, I learned that the following in the preamble will automatically center the contents of figures and tables in floats. It works for me.

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
   \@float{figure}
 }{%
   \@float{figure}[#1]%
 }%
 \centering
}{%
 \end@float
}


\renewenvironment{table}[1][]{%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
   \@float{table}
 }{%
   \@float{table}[#1]%
 }%
 \centering
}{%
 \end@float
}
```