# horizontally center table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Strangely in this MWE the table is shifted to the left but in my original document I have exactly the same code but the table is centered. Can anyone solve the mystery?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Robustness checks---Organised events}
\begin{tabular}{lc} \hline
VARIABLES & Org. event \\ \hline
 &  \\
Price shock & -0.212 \\
 & (0.177) \\
 &  \\
Observations & 2,226 \\
Number of city\_group & 37 \\
R-squared & -0.021 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as why the table is centered in your original document, perhaps you are suing a solution similar to [How can I center all tables in a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/how-can-i-center-all-tables-in-a-document), but without seeing the code it is difficult to know for sure.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Adding `\centering` after `\begin{table}` will center the table:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was used to add the margins so that the centering effect can be seen.
- Using `centering` is preferred over the `center` environment as the environment adds additional vertical space.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Robustness checks---Organised events}
\begin{tabular}{lc} \hline
VARIABLES & Org. event \\ \hline
 &  \\
Price shock & -0.212 \\
 & (0.177) \\
 &  \\
Observations & 2,226 \\
Number of city\_group & 37 \\
R-squared & -0.021 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterGrill, for now I'll use centering to solve this. In a rush for a deadline. I'll come back to this mystery a bit later. Cheers