# Centering all tables in a document with etoolbox

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

(I know there are already other questions about centering tables such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/how-can-i-center-all-tables-in-a-document). This question is specific to etoolbox.)

How do I center all tables using etoolbox? I can do

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\table}{\centering}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    cat & 123 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and this works. But why not the following with etoolbox?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\centering}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    cat & 123 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's see how `table` is defined in `article.cls`:

```
\newenvironment{table}
  {\@float{table}}
  {\end@float}
```

What's the difference in your two methods? The first is equivalent to having defined

```
\newenvironment{table}
  {\@float{table}\centering}
  {\end@float}
```

while the second is mostly equivalent to

```
\newenvironment{table}
  {\centering\@float{table}}
  {\end@float}
```

Here's where things go wrong: among the duties of `\@float` there is calling `\@xfloat`, which in turn does `\@parboxrestore`. This command sets LaTeX in a "predictable state" when starting a `\parbox` or a `minipage`; in particular it issues commands that set up text justification.

A possible place where acting more sensibly is the last macro called by `\@xfloat`, that is, `\@floatboxreset`:

```
\def\@floatboxreset{%
  \reset@font
  \normalsize
  \@setminipage}
```

If you say

```
\addto\@floatboxreset{\centering}
```

all of your floats will be centered. If you want only tables and not figures, then

```
\addto\table{\centering}
```

is good.

Note. Before using `\g@addto@macro` or `\addto`, make yourself certain that the macro you want to modify has no argument; for macros with arguments, use `\addtocmd` (or the similar commands). Better yet, use the facilities provided by `xpatch` that act on the "correct" command.

Answer (score 5):

You may be surprised, but `\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\centering}` works and centers all tables - as long as they don't contain paragraph breaks, but you don't need them commonly for working with `tabular` & Co.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\centering}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    cat & 123 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you expand on why `\AtEndEnvironment` works? At first glance, this seems very hackish. But, if it works is works.

Comment: This didn't work for me in a more complex project, so beware it's fragility.
`\AtEndEnvironment{table}   {\centering\addvspace{\myGlue}} % not centered`