# Apply few commands to all tables

Tags: tables, environments

I'm trying to modify the table environment to apply `small` and `centering`, along with `\figuversion{tabular}` (this is some font-specific stuff), to all tables in the document.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Here is how I tried to do this:

```
\renewenvironment{table}
    {%
        \@float{table}%
        \small%
        \centering%
        \figureversion{tabular}%
    }%
    {%
        \end@float%
    }
```

However, optional placement identifier is lost here, i.e., if I write `\begin{table}[h!]`, I get the table, and [h!] is printed above the table.

Here is the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}%
    {%
        \@float{table}%
        \small%
        \centering%
        %\figuversion{tabular}%
    }%
    {%
        \end@float%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hbox{}

\begin{table}[b!]
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        Entry 1 & Entry 2 \\
        Entry 3 & Entry 4
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

P.S. I cannot use the `floatrow` package as it clashes with the `float` package that is not used directly, but some package in my document requires it.

---

EDIT: This question has already been answered. I repeat the solution here:

```
\renewenvironment{table}[#1][ht]
    {%
        \@float{table}[#1]%
        \small%
        \centering%
        \figureversion{tabular}%
    }%
    {%
        \end@float%
    }
```

Comment: Probably you can make use of the second approach (`\renewenvironment{table}[1]...`)  in [Stefan Kottwitz' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6036/134144)  to [How can I center all tables in a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6033/134144)

Comment: Thanks for indicating that there is already a post with a similar question. I'll mark this question as a duplicate.